# withRouter of react-router not working & gives error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have created a login form & redirecting a user to accounts page after successful login from actions like this: `dispatch(push('/account'))`, so it's changing the URL but the component is not getting rendered. So as per the doc including `withRouter` with fix this, but as I include that I get some error like:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Login/index.tsx:94:27
    TS2345: Argument of type 'ComponentClass<Pick<LoginProps, never>> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<LoginProps>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentConstructor<Pick<LoginProps, never> & WithRouterProps>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<LoginProps, never>> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<LoginProps>; }' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<Pick<LoginProps, never> & WithRouterProps>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<LoginProps, never>> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentType<LoginProps>; }' provides no match for the signature '(props: Pick<LoginProps, never> & WithRouterProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.
```

here is my login component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../../actions';

import { Spinner, Input } from '../../common';

import LoginProps from './interface';
import mapStateToProps from './mapToProps';

class LoginForm extends React.Component<LoginProps, any> {
    onEmailChange(event: any) {
        this.props.emailChanged(event.target.value);
    }

    onPasswordChange(event: any) {
        this.props.passwordChanged(event.target.value);
    }

    onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.props;

        this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-container">
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {
    emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser
})(LoginForm));

Versions:
"react-redux": "^5.0.2",
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.7"
```

Comment: What does the `LoginProps` component look like? Error seems to indicate it's a stateless component. Also, there's a typo in the `LoginForm` but maybe that's just on SO and not your actual code.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I have updated my login component, please check & yes it's stateless, since using redux so reducer taking care of all the state handling

Comment: Still appears to be a typo - `class LoginForm extends React.Component<LoginProps, any> {`

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I am sorry can't see the typo & its not only with my login component its for other component as well, I am getting same error

Comment: This code is not valid `class LoginForm extends React.Component<LoginProps, any> {`

Comment: @BrettDeWoody can you please help me what I can use here? seriously I have tried many things but nothing is working out :(

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal did you ever  figure this out ?? I am having the same issues.

Comment: @29er yeah you have to redirect from the component itself, what you can do, dispatch success action and on success use history.push to redirect the user, you will get history in the component, so you can use something like `this.props.history.push()`